# Checking if popup window is already open while browsing another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check that popup is already opened?

```
var popup = null;
$('#menu').bind('click', function(e) {
    if (popup == null || popup.closed )
        popup = window.open (...);
});
```

The above JQuery code works when in the same page. When the user browse to another page with, still with element `#menu`, popup variable will be `null`. Any idea on this?

When a popup is aleady opened, I don't want the same popup to open.

How to check if a window with a given name already opened?

Thanks

Comment: You can get the handle by doing window.open("","handle")

Comment: ok, i understand the handle that you mean. How to check if a window with a given name already opened?